# Calling main from another function

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

I am new to C, so forgive me if this query is basic.

I want to call main() from another function, and make the program run infinitely. The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void message();

int main()
{
    message();

    return 0;
}

void message()
{
    printf("This is a test message. \n");

    main();
}
```

I expect to see this program run infinitely. However, it runs for some time and then stops suddenly. Using a counter variable, which I printed alongside the test message, I found that the statement "This is a test message." is printed 174608 times after which I get an error message

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

and the program terminates. What does this error mean? And why does the program only run 174608 times (why not infinitely)?

Comment: Does your machine have infinite RAM?

Comment: When a method is called, the return address is put on the stack. When the method returns, the address is taking from the stack again. But your methods never return, they call each other in turns. So after 174608 calls, your stack is simply full. And this stack overlow results in the segmentation fault you receive. There is no clearer error message, because a stack overflow corrupts the whole process and makes error handling very difficult.

Comment: Answer René provided is correct and should be an answer not just a comment.  I just want to add that you should never call main function in your program. Never. If you want infinite loop use while(1) or for(;;).

Comment: @James Bond. Do you really know who calls Main() function of your program? Did you really try this code for an infinite loop run?

Comment: @RenéVogt thank you for that beautiful answer. I completely understand now. I did not know about this concept. I will always keep that in mind.

Comment: @Isrom I read somewhere that you can call a function in another function, even main(). So I tried doing that. I didn't particularly want to implement an infinite loop, but I did expect the program to run infinitely. Also, why is it NOT advisable to call the main() function?

Answer (score 1):

You have stack overflow from infinite recursion. Make infinite loop in `main`:

```
int main()
{
  while (1)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's the name of the site!

Comment: @Kupiakos That is it :)

Answer (score 1):

The mutual recursion costs stack space. If you put the recursion in `main()` itself, the compiler *may* recognise the *tail recursion*, and replace it by iteration. [for fun and education, **don't try this at home, children** ...] :

```
#include <stdio.h>      

void message(); 

int main()
{
    message();  

    return main();
}       

void message()  
{       
    printf("This is a test message. \n");
}
```

GCC recognises the tail recursion in optimisation level=2 and above.
main.s output for gcc -O2 -S main.c:

```
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        .p2align 4,,7
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        call    message
        jmp     .L4
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not equivalent to `while(1) {...}` or `for(;;) {...}`, which give you infinite loops.

Every time a function(for example, `main()` or `message()`) is called, some values are pushed into the *stack*. When functions are called too many times, your stack get filled, and finally overflow, giving you a "stack overflow" error.

Note that this error has nothing to do with this site, although they happen to have the same name :)